Federated dataloader deprecated?
In the federated Learning code below, I'm using Pysyft. the goal is to distribute the FashionMNIST dataset to  different clients
federated_train_loader = syft.FederatedDataLoader(
    datasets.FashionMNIST('../data', train=True, download=True,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                       transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                   ]))
    .federate(client_list),
    batch_size=args['batch_size'], shuffle=True)

and the error is
AttributeError: module 'syft' has no attribute 'FederatedDataLoader'
I tried many solutions but nothing worked. please help !

Yes, it was removed long ago.  You might check syft.core.remote_dataloader.  https://openmined.github.io/PySyft/api_reference/syft.core.remote_dataloader.remote_dataloader.html

I'm using Syft version 0.8.6 and when using this code it doesn't recognize core. how should I use it correctly?
`remote_dataloaders = {}
for worker, subset in zip(remote_workers, subsets):
remote_loader = syft.core.remote_dataloader.remote_dataloader(
DataLoader(subset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True), worker
)
remote_dataloaders[worker.id] = remote_loader`


Did you import syft.core.remote_dataloader?
